# Post-Build event not triggered by Octopus & Team City for C# Project

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I added a Post-Build scropt to my .csproj.  Checked it into TFS.  I see Team City builds fine.

But when OctoDeploy pushes that nuget package for that build, I do not see that post-build script copying a folder to the bin of that project which is what the script does.  It works fine locally on my PC but just is never triggered if OctoDeploy pushes my build to our dev or stage servers.

Not sure where to start.  If you need more info let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a post build script, then you're talking about a script that is run at build time.  Octopus doesn't run any part of the build, it deploys the artifacts of the build.

If you are trying to run a post deploy script, check out the docs at http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/PowerShell+scripts.